# In the program or during the program?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the correct way to say I will learn the subject XYZ which is a part of the program ABC?

Is it "I will learn marketing strategies in the MBA program" or "I will learn marketing strategies during the MBA program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put emphasis on the specific strategies which are presented *in* the program, you should use '**in**'. However, if you want to imply that you will learn some strategies *during* the course of the program, use '**during**'.

Answer (score 0):

**"In"** indicates that **XYZ** is a part of the program **ABC**.
**"During"** can simply indicate a period of time. For example, you can learn **XYZ** as something optional when you pass the program **ABC** (which may not include **XYZ** as a mandatory component).